# Serve pdf file by location in nginx

Tags: nginx, pdf

I'd like to serve a unique pdf file by location in nginx.

I followed the instruction here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023339/serve-pdf-file-by-location-in-nginx

and I did:

```
location /xxx-privacy-disclosure/ {
    alias /var/www/public_html/domain.net/xxx-privacy-disclosure/;
    index xxx-privacy-disclosure.pdf;
}
```

Everything is working except
a `.pdf` file is downloaded (without the filename)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use a URL that ends with a filename, for example `/xxx-privacy-disclosure.pdf` rather than `/xxx-privacy-disclosure/`.

Comment: It will be too easy! Unfortunately my collegue just sent a DEM without the file extension, so I can't use it

Comment: Why not just use a redirect, then?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton thanks for the suggestion! May you kindly give me an example to how accomplish a redirect with nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `index` directive and replace it with, e.g. `return 302` to make a redirect.

```
location /xxx-privacy-disclosure/ {
    alias /var/www/public_html/domain.net/xxx-privacy-disclosure/;
    return 302 xxx-privacy-disclosure.pdf;
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried and in the url the redirection works (the url is the whole path including the pdf) but I receive a too-many-redirect error in chrome

Comment: I solved moving the pdf in another folder (in this case root) respect the "location" directive. And it works like a charm! Thanks a lot! I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation for add "useful" state